# Convert an Array of Integer to Date-Objects

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, datetime, timestamp, epoch.js

I have an array of integer **epoch time** that I would like to convert to date-type objects:

```
masked_array(data=[3.61463040e+09, 3.61463042e+09, 3.61463043e+09, ...,
               3.61471677e+09, 3.61471678e+09, 3.61471680e+09],
         mask=False,
   fill_value=1e+20)
```

I have the following code that is supposed to iterate through the array and convert each number into a date object and save into **.csv** file:

```
timestamp = d.variables['time'][:]
timestamp = timestamp.transpose()
for sublist in timestamp:
print([datetime.strptime(str(item), "%Y%m%d") for item in sublist])
np.savetxt("time.csv", timestamp)
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way where I am able to do this?

Comment: what is your data source? `d.variables['time'][:]` looks like it's coming from something like a netcdf...

Comment: Yes. Here I am reading time dimension from a netcdf file. Even I have tried with this also: 
`import datetime`
`timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: did you have a look at [num2date](https://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4/index.html#netCDF4.num2date) from the netcdf package? the docs are a bit cryptic but the function is quite helpful

Comment: No. I didn't try with `num2date` . Can you suggest me solution for earlier method, because I am not that much aware with `num2date` module.

Comment: ok I provided a minimal example what you could do - but note that time variable in netcdf normally contains a unit and can easily be casted to datetime using `num2date`. you can find examples if you e.g. run a google search for "python netcdf num2date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your input array contains POSIX seconds since the epoch timestamps, you could e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import numpy as np

times = np.ma.masked_array(data=[3.61463040e+09, 3.61463042e+09, 3.61463043e+09,
                                 3.61471677e+09, 3.61471678e+09, 3.61471680e+09],
                           mask=False, fill_value=1e+20)

timestr = np.array([datetime.fromtimestamp(t, tz=timezone.utc)
                    .strftime("%Y%m%d")
                    for t in times.data])
# timestr
# array(['20840717', '20840717', '20840717', '20840717', '20840717',
#        '20840718'], dtype='<U8')
```

Comment: I have tried this method, but an error is coming `TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got results by making some changes in your code. `array(['2018-07-17 00:00:01', '2018-07-17 00:00:16',
       '2018-07-17 00:00:31', ..., '2018-07-17 23:59:29',
       '2018-07-17 23:59:44', '2018-07-17 23:59:58'], dtype='<U19')` Now, I'm not able to save it in csv file. Please help me for same. Thank you in advance.